# which prepositions is correct? In or from?

Tags: prepositions

I wonder which one is better: "She is a pupil/student IN an American junior high school" or "FROM an American junior high school"?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Both could be fine.  Can you please add more detail about who this person is and where you are introducing her?  For example, is she currently attending an American junior high school, or is she currently studying elsewhere?

Comment: She currently is.

Comment: Is which?  There is no tax on words -- please feel free to use as many as you need to make the situation perfectly clear.

Comment: Where is this being said?

Comment: Sorry, I meant she currently is attending an American junior high.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say.

If she is IN the school, she is still a pupil there.

If she is FROM the school, she has left the school and is no longer a pupil there.

Comment: I think *from* has more to do with location. If said in a foreign school, one could say "She is a student **from** an American junior high school."

Comment: @user3169 It could be location or it could refer to other features. For example, she could be from a French-language school or a fee-paying school or a school that concentrated on sport. Whatever the case, she is no longer at the school.